# Maximum Penetration Depth for Ultrasound

Tags: waves, acoustics

How do you define the maximum penetration depth of an ultrasound? I'm assuming it means the depth at which the wave has attenuated to a certain small percentage of the original intensity of the incident beam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is customary when talking about penetration length to mean the length when the intensity has dropped to 36.8% of its surface value. This is motivated by the fact that the intensity decays as $I(z)=I_o e^{-z/d}$. See you need a constant of dimension [Lenght] in the exponent denominator, so you call that $d$ the penetration length then its immediate that the intensity at our defined length is $I(d)=I_o e^{-1/1} = 0.368 I_o$.

Notice this is just a natural convention, all scientists could have agreed to write $I(z)=I_o e^{-2z/\pi d}$ which is still dimensionally correct but corresponds to a different numerical value of our chosen length. All that matters in any case is the "length scale" which is any of those $d$s up to a constant of order unity.